# Cannot get jedis connection getting org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException

Tags: redis, jedis

I am upgrading my spring boot application to spring boot 3 and java version 17. Current version used for redis is not yet changed and not touched or modified for the redis configuration. But after migration and able to build but when deploying to pcf server getting org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get jedis connection

Below is the dependency currently i am using
`implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:2.7.6' implementation 'redis.clients:jedis'`

`implementation("io.netty:netty-codec-http2") { version { strictly "4.1.100.Final" } }`

I have a strong feeling in using the below

```
io.netty
```

can someone help me out for this issue to be solved. Before migration same code working, but after migration same code not working.